# Surfaces in relation to basic topology.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I need to calculate the fundamental group of the space obtained by punching k holes in the sphere.

I understand the spaces H(p) and M(q), with H(p) being the sphere with p handles added and M(q) as the sphere with q Mobius strips sewn in, and I believe I understand their fundamental groups and sort of how to calculate them. I just can't seem to understand how these concepts relate if they do, and therefore, how to find the fundamental group of the space obtained by punching k holes in the sphere.

Comment: You seem to be referencing the classification theorem of compact surfaces without boundary. That is not necessarily the case here because, as you can see, your surface is not compact.

Comment: **Hint:** What do you get topologically if you remove *one* point/small disk from the sphere?

Comment: $S^m\backslash\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m\backslash\{x'_1,\ldots,x'_{n-1}\}$ (note: one less point) which is either contractible (n=1) or homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of $n-1$ spheres (when $n>1$) of dimension $m-1$. The same applies if we replace points with small enough disks. Also, I'm not sure how your problem is related to handles and Mobius strips to be honest. At best this is an overcomplicated approach.